# How can I check if CMake was called with --graphviz?

Tags: cmake, graphviz

I have stuff in my build that depends on the `.dot` file generated by CMake's [`--graphviz`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) option.

```
if(cmake was called with --graphviz)
    # add targets that depend on --graphviz output
endif()
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Any special reason you link to the docs of CMake 3. **2** ? Anyway, I guess checking for the existence of a [generated file `foo.dot`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html) would be too much of a restriction?

Comment: @Friedrich No, that was a mistake. Had been the first result from Google and I didn't realize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a cursory look at the docs and source code of CMake, I don't think this is possible- at least- not at the time of this writing.

See https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx. `GenerateGraphViz` is called in `cmake::Generate` ***after*** the global generator's generate step is performed, and `cmake::Generate` is called after the *configure* step is performed (see `cmake::Run`). And it's not implemented as a generated buildsystem target. It's a custom procedure (C++ function) in the CMake executable. Also, the only way that the block in which the call to `GenerateGraphViz` is made is entered is if the `!this->GraphVizFile.empty()` condition is met; I'd hoped that the presence of any [`CMakeGraphVizOptions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeGraphVizOptions.html#module:CMakeGraphVizOptions) would also trigger the graph generation, since those are CMake variables, which would be easy for your CMake configuration to check for during the configure step, but sadly that's not the case.

I'd hoped that [`CMAKE_ARGV<N>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARGV0.html) would be useful here, but that's only for CMake in Script Mode. It's not available in non-script-mode.